# Remove commit status from repo

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, git-commit

I'm playing with few CI tools and they update commit status in github. Is it possible to delete these statuses? I've got a lot of commits with pending status and these commits will not be successful because CI is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a way to delete a status, be it with the web frontend or the [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/).